# conan user cmd generates Invalid server response

Tags: artifactory, conan

I installed Artifactory Community Edition for C/C++ 6.3.3 on windows 7 and created a conan reposotory. on the same machine I do have conan 1.7.3. I added the repository to the list of remotes

```
λ conan remote add test http://localhost:8082/artifactory/api/conan/testtcc
λ conan remote list
conan-center: https://conan.bintray.com [Verify SSL: True]
conan-transit: https://conan-transit.bintray.com [Verify SSL: True]
poco: https://api.bintray.com/conan/pocoproject/conan [Verify SSL: True]
test: http://localhost:8082/artifactory/api/conan/testtcc [Verify SSL: True]
```

but when I try to add a user I got this error

```
λ conan user admin -r test -p                                            
Please enter a password for "admin" account:                             
ERROR: b''                                                               

Invalid server response, check remote URL and try again. [Remote: test]
```

Comment: quick hints: the poco libraries are already linked to conan-center, so you might not need that remote. The conan-transit remote is mostly deprecated and broken stuff, I wouldn't recommend to use it unless you want to do some forensics on old recipes to build packages for libraries based on them

Comment: What is the output if you try to do a ``conan search "*" -r=test``?

Comment: thank you @drodri, the two remotes were added just for tests and I removed them.
`λ conan user
Current user of remote 'conan-center' set to: 'None' (anonymous)
Current user of remote 'test' set to: 'None' (anonymous)
conan search "*" -r=test
ERROR: Permission denied for user: 'None'. [Remote: test]`

Comment: Allow Anonymous Access on artifactory is checked. I added admin user without specifying pasword
`λ conan user admin -r test                                      
Changed user of remote 'test' from 'None' (anonymous) to 'admin'
λ conan search "*" -r=test    
ERROR: Permission denied for user: 'admin'. [Remote: test]      `

Comment: Don't know what it could be. I suggest contacting the conan team (in their email, or in github issues) and try to solve the issue there, might need some discussion and further details, which SO might not be the best forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @drodri, the error message is not relevant, in fact the problem is related to conan proxy configuration. I am connecting to conan-center via proxy and with no proxy to local remote "test".
adding `no_proxy_match = http://localhost:8082*` fixed the issue.
[known issue](https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/2315)